# With arc will this cause a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have some code that confuses me

The code is:

```
for (int i=0; i < numOfRooms; i++) {

    NSString* roomName = [self getString:themessageReceived :packetstart + index];
    NSLog(@"roomName is %@ with length %d roomID %d",roomName, roomName.length,roomID);
    [roomsInTheClub insertRoom:roomID :roomName];
    index += roomName.length;
    index++;

}
```

Now originally I was thinking, seeing `NSString` is non mutable I would need to create a `NSMutableString` above the loop, then change the `getString` call to return a mutable `NSString`, or cast the return from the call

I am amazed the above actually works and allows the same `NSString` to be created over an over again

I could change it to send the `NSString` from `getString` directly to the `insertRoom` code and bypass actually creating an `NSString` each pass through the loop

I am puzzled over this

Is ARC dealing with this automatically, allowing me to declare the same `NSString` over and over again in the loop

Or have a created a Memory Leak ?

Thanks In Advance

Phil

Comment: Unless `getString::` is doing something unusual, it's not the same string.  It's the same variable but pointing to a different actual string object each time through.

Comment: `getString::` is an awful method name;  it doesn't say what is going on, nor describe the arguments, and it is prefixed with `get` which is reserved for very special purposes (this isn't it).  `insertRoom::` is also a bad name.

Comment: The only memory leak will be remembering what the methods do in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say a string is immutable, they mean that the object that your string pointer points to is immutable. But your pointer can point to a new immutable string, without affecting that previous string object. You can confirm that you're looking at a new object by logging the address of the object in your loop, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"roomName=%p", roomName);
```

You'll undoubtedly see a new address for each iteration, proving that you're dealing with a new object.

In answer to your question, no, this will not cause a leak. The string object will be deallocated automatically when you remove the last strong reference to it. If your `insertRoom` method is adding it to an array, for example, then obviously the string will be retained as long as the array is, but when the array is released, so will your string room name. Bottom line, this shouldn't cause a leak.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I tried the %p in NSLog and all is well as you said :-)